# AOT issue with mvvmcross

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm unable to build Xamarin projects that reference MvvmCross as I receive the error:

Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/chriskoiak/Documents/Initial/Mobile Clients/xxxx/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Build/Cirrious.CrossCore.dll' (MT3001)
Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/chriskoiak/Documents/Initial/Mobile Clients/xxxx/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Build/Cirrious.MvvmCross.dll' (MT3001)

This error occurred after I upgraded to xcode5, mvvmcross 3.0.12 Xamarin.iOS 7.0.0.11

Has anyone else experienced this problem or can suggest a fix?

Thanks

Comment: It's an AOT compiler error message from a release of xamarin.ios in the last few hours - try their support email

Comment: Same problem here. Only with the DownloadCache plugin.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a little bug that has appeared in the initial Xamarin.iOS 7 release, caused by the transition to "real" PCL reference assemblies on OS X. The developers are working to get this fixed right away, but in the meantime there is a work-around. Specifically, you can add `-linkskip=System.Net -linkskip=System.Windows` to the "Additional mtouch arguments" under Project Options -> Build -> iOS Build. This will tell the linker not to try to link System.Net or System.Windows.

Update:
A corrected version of Xamarin.iOS (7.0.1) has now been released to the alpha channel. When using this latest version, the `linksip` work-around should no longer be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but your link leads to an angry "Access Denied" page!

Comment: Also `-linkskip` seems to have fix it for me! Thanks!

Comment: Not for me, the link to System.Windows seem to have been broken so ICommand is not recognized anymore. Then in iOS the lambda's on ICommands cannot be converted to strings anymore.... More digging :(

Comment: Hugo - remember to reference the System.Windows assembly as described here http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/3012-pushed-to-mvvmcross-binaries-not.html

Comment: Glad this is working for you guys! @MattBurland thanks for the heads-up on the bad link. I removed it. In any case, a note about the fix should appear in the release notes for the next version.

Comment: @HugoLogmans Maybe you're also hitting [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901310/tinyioc-xamarin-ios-linker-settings)?

Comment: @Brendan: looks like it, but didn't help.

Comment: This issue has now been resolved with the latest release of Xamarin.iOS