# Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly (MVVMCross DLL)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I started some weeks ago testing MVVMCross and I managed to compile in debug mode for simulator.
However, when I try to compile for Ad Hoc or debug mode for Device, I'm getting following errors:

```
Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/SomeDirectory/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/mtouch-cache/Build/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.dll' (MT3001)
Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/SomeDirectory/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/mtouch-cache/Build/Cirrious.MvvmCross.dll' (MT3001)
Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly '/SomeDirectory/obj/iPhone/Ad-Hoc/mtouch-cache/Build/Cirrious.CrossCore.dll' (MT3001)
```

I'm linking more MVVMCross libraries, but it seems only these 3 are mentioned. I tried to play around with changing the Mac DLLs with the Windows DLLs but error stays (at a certain point I was getting 5 errors instead of 3 when changing them)

I'm using latest stable version of Xamarin.iOS + MVVMCross 3.0.12

Any Idea?

Regards, Matt

Comment: possible duplicate of [AOT issue with mvvmcross](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899518/aot-issue-with-mvvmcross)

Comment: It's an AOT compiler error message from a release of xamarin.ios in the last few days - try their support email for patch